# .net6 System.Collections.Immutable clashing with nuget dependencies?

Tags: .net, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a Roslyn Analyzer project for `.net6.0` and migrating this from a `.netstandard2.0` project of the same purpose.

It seems the latest `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` NuGet dependency (a requirement for Analyzers) requires `System.Collections.Immutable` 6.0.0 and .net6 comes with `System.Collections.Immutable` 6.0.0 as a default dependency (but they appear to be different version numbers).

It appears when Roslyn tries to run the Analyzer it fails.

Has anyone seen anything similar, or have a solution to make the two different dependencies of the same version number work together?

All this code works correctly in .net standard 2.0 with an older version of `System.Collections.Immutable`.

> CS8032    An instance of analyzer MyProject.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.MissingAuthorizeAttribute cannot be created from C:\Git\MyProject\MyProject.CodeAnalysis\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyProject.CodeAnalysis.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..   MyProject.Common    C:\Git\MyProject\MyProject.Common\CSC   1   Active

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this.

For anyone who may see similar, the latest `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` version at the time had a very small but more recent version of `System.Collections.Immutable` than the compiler.

- I was using latest .net 6.0 sdk (6.0.**401**) and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` 4.3.0.
- Changing it to 4.0.0 resolved the issue.